# UITableView deleteRows not updating IndexPaths causing crash index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Calling following code on success of an API call for deleting item from list

```
self?.myWishlistArry?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
self?.myWishListTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
```

Following is closure for delete button

```
        myWishlistCell.closureForRemoveBtn = {
        [weak self]
        (productId, storeid) in
        self?.callAlertViewForRemoved(productid: productId, storeId: storeid, indexPath: indexPath)
    }
```

Following is code to show alert for user confirmation.

```
    func callAlertViewForRemoved(productid :String, storeId: String, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: AppLocalString.ITEM_NOT_AVAILABLE_TEXT.localized(), message: AppLocalString.MY_EXLUDE_TEXT.localized(), preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: AppLocalString.ALERT_YES.localized(), style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        if self.listBool == false {
            //self.listBool = true
            self.callRemoveWishlist(productid :productid, storeId: storeId, indexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }
    
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: AppLocalString.Cancel_ORDER.localized(), style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
    }
    
    // Add the actions
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    
}
```

Following is code api remove

```
    func callRemoveWishlist(productid :String, storeId: String, indexPath: IndexPath)  {
    
    listBool = true
    addLoading(view: view, random: removeRandom)
    let addFriendsBaseUrl = AppStrings.baseUrl + AppStrings.addToWishlistAPI
    var paramDict = [String : Any]()
    
    paramDict = ["type" : "remove",
                 "productid" : productid,
                 "storeid" : "\(storeId)",
        "userid" : UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: AppStrings.userid) ?? ""]
    
    
    let baseParams = Utility.appendBaseParams(toDict: paramDict as! [String : String])
    
    NetworkResponseManager.getDataFromUrl(url: addFriendsBaseUrl, parameters: baseParams as! [String : String] , completionHandler: {
        [weak self]
        (response, error) in
        self?.listBool = false
        if (error == nil) {
            
            if let responseDict = response {
                
                let responseDict = AddToWishlistModel(JSON(responseDict))
                self?.removeLoading(view: self?.view, random: self?.removeRandom)
                if responseDict.status == 1
                {
                    self?.myWishlistArry?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    self?.myWishListTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
                } else {
                    self?.showToast(message: AppLocalString.OOPS_TEXT.localized())
                }
            }
        } else {
             self?.showToast(message: AppLocalString.OOPS_TEXT.localized())
        }
    })
}
```

Other table view code

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return self.myWishlistArry?.count ?? 0
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Now this code is working for first time but causing crash if try to delete another item saying index out of range. Consider if there are four items in list **T1, T2, T3 and T4**
first time if **I delete T2** item indexPath.row value is 1 now item and row is deleted **if I delete another Item say T4** the value of **indexPath.row comes out to be 3 instead of 2** why this is happening why indexpaths are not update?

Comment: How do you call this code?

Comment: on success of api call tried calling with DispatchQueue.main.async  as well still crashing

Comment: The code itself won't cause a crash unless it's executed in a closure where the index path is captured. Please add the context code.

Comment: yeah called from closure on click of a button

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, you need to give more of it.

Comment: @amodkanthe If you call it in clojure in cellForRowAt, the indexpath is different (set to value which was correct in time when cellForRowAt was called). You should do deletion based on the id of the wishlist item (something that wont change when the item is deleted)

Comment: added entire code please check

Comment: Why not just call reloadData after removing from the datasource? It will have to be done in main queue

Comment: @cora It's inefficient to reload the entire table view and you get rid of the animation.

Comment: True, but sometimes we need to try things to follow the bread crumbs :P It would not have solved the problem at all, just a confirmation that the index becomes different sometime after the cell is tapped and the response from the server.

Comment: @cora My answer solves the issue reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the entire code, it looks like the problem is the clojure

If you call it in clojure in cellForRowAt, the indexpath is different (set to value which was correct in time when cellForRowAt was called). You should do deletion based on the id of the wishlist item (something that wont change when the item is deleted).

For example create a method like:

```
func deleteWish(productId: string) {
    for i in myWishlistArry ?? [] {
        let product = myWishlistArry[i]
        if let product.productId == productId {
             myWishlistArry?.remove(at: i)
             myWishListTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i, 0)], with: .right)
        }
    }

}
```

and call in clojure `deleteWish(productId: idOfDeletedProduct)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the index path is captured and not being updated after the order of the cells changes.

The solution:

In the cell declare the closure to pass also the cell

```
var closureForRemoveBtn : ((UITableViewCell, String, String) -> Void)?
```

and call it

```
closureForRemoveBtn?(self, productId, storeId)
```

In `cellForRow` get the index path from the **actual** cell

```
myWishlistCell.closureForRemoveBtn = {
    [weak self]
    (actualCell, productId, storeid) in
    let actualIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: actualCell)!
    self?.callAlertViewForRemoved(productid: productId, storeId: storeid, indexPath: actualIndexPath)
}
```

---

Or maybe even simpler

```
var closureForRemoveBtn : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

///

closureForRemoveBtn?(self)

///

myWishlistCell.closureForRemoveBtn = {
    [weak self] actualCell in
    let actualIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: actualCell)!
    self?.callAlertViewForRemoved(productid: actualCell.productId, storeId: actualCell.storeid, indexPath: actualIndexPath)
}
```